# Placing text in section after image placed in body (background-image)

Tags: css

I have a question.

So I want to keep my background image that goes below nav bar perfectly but i want my text in section.. .. to go after the background image. i have this in body now:

```css
body {
        background-image: url("vissow.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        }
```

and it look something like this:

[Page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcdGF.png)

So I would like to go with text after the image, any ideas?

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day, Tim.

Comment: Could you be more clear , by posting a picture of what you want your output to be like? Ans also your current progress.

Comment: let's say something like this after the picture: https://i.snag.gy/GyYBti.jpg

Comment: I want to have content to be placed below picture, let's say ex. latest news, latest pictures, a short text about the page etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use section tags to create two sections after header/navigation. Use background image in first section and use text in second section.

Comment: I went for a table method. for now i'm just positioning inside elements hope it works out fine